# jquery $(this).data selector

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
// Rate videos start
$('[value="bad"]').click(function (e) {
    console.log($(this));
    alert($(this).data("primary"));
});
```

```php
echo '<div class="carousel-inner">';
echo '<div class="item active">';
echo '<h4>' . $vid->VIDEO_NAME . '</h4>';
echo '<input type="text" class="" data-primary="' . $vid->ID . '" value="' . $vid->ID . '">';
echo '<video width="500" height="281" controls>';
echo '<source src="' . base_url() . $vid->VIDEO_URL . '" type="video/mp4">';
echo 'Your browser does not support the video tag.';
echo '</video>';
echo '</div>';
echo '</div>';
echo '</div>';
```

I'm trying to get the ID of each video element but it returns undefined.

Comment: There are no elements with `value=bad` in provided code sample.

Comment: Please give snippet of the rendered html.

Comment: Did my answer work for you?

Comment: hi I'm new to this stackoverflow senario. Can you please teach me how to provide snippet of rendered html? @u_mulder ,@DecoderReloaded

Comment: @EshanGurusinghe Did my answer solve your problem? If it did please mark it as accepted. Thanks

Comment: There are a few typos in your code, such as no space after echo and alert is missing the a. I fixed these in my suggested edit.

Answer (score 0):

Set an identifier like `id` or `class` on your text field, then add a listener to the click event on that object:

```js
// If you set by Class
$('.textToClick').click(function (e)
{
  alert($(this).data("primary"));
});

// If you set by ID
$('#textToClick').click(function (e)
{
  alert($(this).data("primary"));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Setting identifier by Class -->
<input type="text" class="textToClick" data-primary="dataPrimaryFromClass" value="Class identifier">

<!-- or setting identifier by id -->
<input type="text" id="textToClick" data-primary="dataPrimaryFromID" value="ID identifier">
```